# "Expected a field name" error in Keil uVision 4 (error#134)

Tags: arm, keil, field-names

I've been developing an embedded project for NXP LPC1774 Arm CortexM3 MCU.For the same project, I have coded many different versions and all worked fine. Today I added two new pin definitions where I choose them to be output pins for GPIO ports with the following line:

```
LPC_GPIO4->DIR |= 0x2000;
```

after this, I started to get the error #134 in every single line where I call a DIR register. I realized some header calls refer to another copy of the same file and I changed it. It did not help. Does anyone have an idea where this error could come from?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem.

In my definitions file, I had a definition for motor direction and named it as DIR. It confused the compiler due to double definition.